# What does divergence of heat flux mean?

Tags: heat-conduction

Before stating my question I will start with two definitions:

1. [**Heat flux**](https://www.toppr.com/guides/physics-formulas/heat-flux-formula/) also named as thermal flux, is referred to as heat flux density, heat-flow density is a flow of energy per unit of area per unit of time. In SI its units are watts per square meter. As heat flux has both a direction and a magnitude, and so it is a vector quantity.
2. In vector calculus, [**divergence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#:%7E:text=In%20vector%20calculus%2C%20divergence%20is%20a%20vector%20operator,from%20an%20infinitesimal%20volume%20around%20a%20given%20point.) is a vector operator that operates on a vector field, producing a scalar field giving the quantity of the vector field's source at each point. More technically, the divergence represents the volume density of the outward flux of a vector field from an infinitesimal volume around a given point.

Now when talking about divergence of heat flux in the case of steady state heat conduction, it is equal to the heat source. I don't understand why do we have to apply a divergence operator on the heat flux, because heat flux it self is a flow per unit area, so why do we apply divergence? It just seems to me as if we are talking about the flux of a flux.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the flux of a flux". The equation you are referring to is $$\vec\nabla\cdot\vec q = \dot Q$$
which is the statement of conservation of heat in differential form. Intuitively, the divergence of a vector field quantifies its tendency to "flow outward" at a given point, so this equation says the more heat you are generating at a point, the more heat will flow away from that point.

A bit more quantitatively, imagine a small region of volume $\Delta V$ containing some point $\vec r_0$. Within this region, $\dot Q(\vec r) \approx \dot Q(\vec r_0)$, and the heat generated per unit time in this region is approximately $$\dot Q(\vec r_0) \Delta V.$$ An important property of the divergence is that the total heat flow out of the region per unit time is approximately $$(\vec \nabla \cdot \vec q)(\vec r_0)\Delta V$$ (the formal statement of this is the divergence theorem). At steady state, all of the heat generated must flow outward, so these two quantities are equal. In the limit of $\Delta V \rightarrow0$, we get the exact equation
$$(\vec \nabla \cdot \vec q)(\vec r_0)=\dot Q(\vec r_0).$$